# defining a abstract copyWIth method in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

How to define a `copyWith` method to be implemented in subclasses of CoreDetail.

```dart
@immutable
abstract class CoreDetail<I extends CoreItem<ID>, ID> {
  final I item;
  final double _qty;
  final double _discount;

  const CoreDetail({
    required this.item,
    double qty = 1,
    double discount = 0,
  })  : _discount = discount,
        _qty = qty;

  double get qty => _qty;

  double get discount => _discount;

}
```

The `copyWith` method signature will look like

```dart
CoreDetail<I,ID>copyWith({
     Item? item,
     double? qty,
     double? discount,
   });
```

The issue will be we can not change the return type to implemented class type.

Comment: "The issue will be we can not change the return type to implemented class type." Why can't you?  An override can be declared to return a narrower type.

Comment: @jamesdlin Since CoreDetail is abstract return type will needs to be broader type

Comment: The method in the abstract base class must be declared to return a broader type, but the overrides in the derived classes can be declared to return narrower types.  An override cannot have narrower *parameters*.